# Why MATLAB is showing "Index exceeds matrix dimensions." Error

Tags: matlab, indexing, bayesian-networks

I am new to MATLAB and trying to learn Bayesian Networks. 
Running this code shows an error

> Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

in line

```
( for r = 1:length(nodes(root(rr)).values))
```

Please help me out with this.

Thanks in Advance

```
function [nodes, edges] = bnMsgPassInitiate(nodes, edges, root)
N = numel(nodes);

for X = 1:N % for every node

nodes(X).lambda = ones(1, length(nodes(X).values)); % l(x) = 1

Z = nodes(X).parents;
for pa = 1:length(Z) % for each parent of X
    edges(Z(pa),X).lambdaX = ones(1, length(nodes(Z(pa)).values)); % lX(z) = 1
end  

Y = nodes(X).children;
for ch = 1:length(Y) % for each child of X
    edges(X,Y(ch)).peyeX = ones(1, length(nodes(X).values)); % peyeY(x)
end

end

numRoots = length(root);
for rr = 1:numRoots
   **for r = 1:length(nodes(root(rr)).values)**
    nodes(root(rr)).peye(r) = nodes(root(rr)).CPT(r);
    nodes(root(rr)).P(r) = nodes(root(rr)).CPT(r);
end
childrenR = nodes(root(rr)).children;
for cr = 1:length(childrenR)
    [nodes, edges] = bnMsgPassSendPiMsg(root(rr), childrenR(cr), nodes, edges, []); %A = []
end
end
```

Comment: Which part of the error don't you understand, "index" or "matrix dimensions"? We can't possibly help because we don't have your inputs.
 https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/debugging-code.html

Comment: nodes= 0x1 struct 
root =1
values= 1x4 cell
CPT= 1x4 cell 
These are my inputs.

Answer (score 2):

'Index exceeds matrix dimensions' occured when you're working with some value that outside of bound. For example, if I have N = [1,2,3], then if I tried to call N(4), then I will get 'Index exceeds matrix dimensions'. And remember, matrix in matlab started from index 1, not 0.

Make sure you check the size of your matrix before working on it using

```
size(yourmatrix)
```

At a glance, your error should be in `root(rr)` or `nodes(root(rr).values)`.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `root(rr)` is larger than the number of elements in `nodes`.

Answer (score 0):

It means that you have specified an index value greater than the limit of your matrix assigned dimensions. For example a "for statement doing 10 loops and you assigned an index value of 301 while your maximum matrix dimension is 300, this will give you an error of " index exceeds matrix dimensions"